# Soft keyboard covers TextView below EditText

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-softkeyboard

I placed a TextView below an EditText to display the latter's character count. This is how it looks like when the EditText is not in focus.

[image]

When the EditText is in focus:

[image]

As you can see, "7/500" has been covered by the TextView.

The XML for my activity:

```
<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="20dp"
    android:paddingTop="10dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/display_photo"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="250dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"/>

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/caption_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="7dp">

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
                android:id="@+id/et_start_photo_story_title"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:gravity="bottom"
                android:maxLength="500"
                android:paddingBottom="15dp"
                android:privateImeOptions="nm"
                android:textColor="@color/black" />
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_character_count"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:textColor="@color/grey700"
            android:textSize="14sp" />
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

I have this line inside my manifest `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"`. I have tried changing the height of the ImageView, but the character count remains hidden when the EditText is in focus.

Comment: Please use android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" in manifest. then you can scroll the view.

Comment: place your `tv_character_count` to right side (**not below**) of `caption_layout` or use `RelativeLayout`. See if this can be doable for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of setting as

`android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"`

try setting as

`android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"`

which will make your view scrollable when edittext is focused.

Comment: That's what I had originally but it cuts off the photo. Any way around this?

Comment: try adding your Scrollview in parent Relativelayout

Comment: @Bargain23 There's only 3 modes for changing in response to the keyboard appearing.  adjustPan (your app will be scrolled if needed to assure the cursor is on screen), adjustResize (your app will be resized to fit the space above the keyboard), and adjustNone (do nothing).  If you have lots of whitespace there's tricks you can do with relative layouts to reduce it, but in the end something has to give-  you now have less space, something isn't going to fit.

Comment: @GabeSechan is there a way to make the TextView always float above the soft keyboard? Or trick the soft keyboard to treat it like it's part of the EditText?

Comment: @Bargain23 No to both of those.  Its just not a part of Google's implementation.  There's also no reliable way of telling that the soft keyboard has been opened to scroll it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

In case you are using dependency injection framework like `com.google.dagger:hilt-android` place the  `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|adjustResize"` in the application section of the manifest instead of the activity section.

Comment: Why would a dependency injection framework affect this?

Comment: I have not carried out the full analysis but after incorporating dependency injection to an existing project (which required extending Application class), the android:windowSoftInputMode was not taking effect until i moved it to the application section. I thought the observation can save somebody some time.